# (React Router v4) Create Routes using map

Tags: reactjs, react-router

for my CryptoCurrencypage I would like to create a Route for every Currency available. I have a Main component which holds all the possible routes, in there I got the cryptodata from redux, mapped over that array and created a route for each currency. When I am on the mainPage(cryptodatalist) and click on one it works perfectly fine, but when I refresh the site or try to directly navigate to a specific details page it fails. How can I make it work?

```
 DetailRoutes = props.cryptos.map(val => {
    return (
      <Route
        key={val.id}
        exact
        path={"/" + val.name}
        crypto={val.symbol}
        render={props => <DetailsPage {...props} />}
      />
    );
  });
```

Comment: How does your Router config look like

Comment: A couple things: 1.  Make sure your routes are still being created after you refresh your page.  2. Check your redux store after you refresh the page and make sure those routing values are still in your store.

Comment: I dont know if I have a Router  config, I just imported the BrowserRouter, wrapped my main component with it, and inside my main component i have a <switch> with multiple <Route>

Comment: how do I make sure, that my routes are still being created after I refresh? because I am pretty sure they are not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not the issue of react-router. What you are actually facing is a problem with registered routes. So, when you navigate from home page to any other page, all routes are in scope for your project.

But when you directly navigate to some other url other than the home page, you'll not be able to render, because the logic for rendering those routes exists at the home page (that is `/` or `root` route )

There are two ways ( that I can think of right now ) -

1. You can tell your server, to redirect to the root path if any request directly lands to some other url.
2. For your current development hack, you can configure your webpack to fallback at the root path by including `publicPath: '/', historyApiFallback: true` in your `webpack.config.js` file.